# Fall or fall down/ fall off

Tags: verbs, usage

Is it correct if I say:

*He was repairing the bulb when he fell.*

(not **fell down** or **fell off**, just *fell* without any preposition after fell)

Comment: Yes, it's ok to use *fell* without an adverb (not a preposition.)("down" and "off" are adverb, here,if there are no objects(noun, pronoun etc) after it)

Comment: btw, people don't usually repair bulbs; they change them.

Comment: @Sam, how do we, as non-native speakers, know that "down" and "off" are adverbs, not prepositions, here? I don't know how to differentiate when they are "prepositions" and when they are "adverbs". Is there an easy way for us notice that?

Comment: @yunus what I said  is a very easy way to do that.

Comment: @Sam, do you mean prespositions become adverbs "if there are no objects(noun, pronoun etc) after them?

Comment: @yunus yes, but not always this method work.